# can't get a response out of eBay's Merchandising API

Tags: webservice-client, ebay-api

This is my first question.. ever... for this illustrious and reverential forum, so if I am rebuked for the content of this question I won't take it personally...

I am attempting to call ebay's merchandising service via the code below, and keep getting a "The request failed with an empty response."   err Response

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //Use the custom class 
        customMerchandisingService svc = new customMerchandisingService();
        //Set the production URL 
        svc.Url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/MerchandisingService?";
        GetMostWatchedItemsRequest request = new GetMostWatchedItemsRequest();
        request.categoryId = "617";
        MerchandisingServiceItemResponse response = svc.getMostWatchedItems(request);

        foreach (Item item in response.itemRecommendations)
        {
            //process results 
            string title = item.title;
            string itemID = item.itemId;

        }

    }

    class customMerchandisingService : MerchandisingAPI.MerchandisingService
    {
        protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
        {
            HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(uri);
            //Set the AppID, Operation, Service, Protocol and Version as HTTP Headers 
            req.Headers.Add("EBAY-SOA-CONSUMER-ID", "Your AppID");
            req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-OPERATION-NAME", "getMostWatchedItems");
            req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-NAME", "MerchandisingService");
            req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-MESSAGE-PROTOCOL", "SOAP11");
            req.Headers.Add("X-EBAY-SOA-SERVICE-VERSION", "1.1.0");
            return req;
        }
    }
```

I googled a bit, and read posts such as the following:

["The request failed with an empty response" when calling a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642454/the-request-failed-with-an-empty-response-when-calling-a-web-service)

I tried playing with my httpeepee's, and keep coming up short.  Basically I was hoping that it wasn't me, that some web developer at eBay (bless his heart) was to blame, today at least.

I guess I was hoping someone on this forum that also develops against eBay's API's could confirm that the merchandising service is working fine for them today, in which case I guess I'll need to keep banging my head against a wall.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ah yes, I messed with the url a bit.. it appeared that the source of this code sample:  https://ebaydts.com/eBayKBDetails?KBid=1507    had an outdated url?  I read the "What's different" at http://developer.ebay.com/Devzone/merchandising/docs/Concepts/MerchandisingAPIGuide.html#whatsdiff   and nothing jumped out at me.. unfortunately...

Comment: Hey now don't all respond at once I might get underwhelmed.  Well I introduced myself to fiddler and I guess I am getting something back in the response a 302 temporarily moved, but no location.  Best lead now is its some kind of bugginess with soap, might try another protocol tomorrow but I hate leaving my comfort zone.  I'm gonna answer my own question if it kills me.  Few more years at this and yall will be callin me the next Jon skeet.